# Why would a Druid use the Awaken spell?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, spells

What is the inspiration for the Awaken spell (found at least in D&D 3.5e)?
 Why would a stereotypical/archetypal druid use it? I'm thinking that it's "unnatural" for an animal or tree to have intelligence, so it seems to offend the druid's preference for what is natural. Does it come from some fiction that justifies it?

*Caveat:* While I can imagine evil and twisted uses, I'm not interested in those. The spell doesn't have the [evil] descriptor, and I'd imagine that it should be useful to druids of all alignments.

Comment: Awaken's description (in Pathfinder at least) partly describes Awaken as a gift of sorts to loyal animal companions. While its use is probably rare, it seems to be primarily used as a reward or as an unconventional method of attack on a character that mistreats their own companion (with the assumption that the animal companion will turn on their master). Having said that, I've yet to have access to it so couldn't tell you if there are more logical situations.

Comment: Plot device, Mr Frodo. Plot device.

Comment: Just a clarification out there, the "non-evil" bit means that I'm not interested in the terrible purposes to which an evil druid might put the spell. I don't think the spell is in any way evil itself, but rather wondering what the point of the spell is for druids in general.

Comment: Quite related : [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/27873/is-there-any-fluff-for-the-druids-a-thousand-faces-ability) where we try to depict druids as something more than "friend of nature"

Comment: *Awaken* is no more unnatural than any other Druid spell. Also, evil druids aren't necessarily in favour of the unnatural: They still have to revere nature, after all. You may want to reconsider your assumptions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about assigning or justifying an alignment for a particular character or behavior. See [meta discussion about what kinds of alignment questions are on topic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5357/4563) for more details.

Comment: @KRyan - I don't have much attachment to this old question. That said, I think my comment above clarifies that this isn't an alignment question. I'll edit my question in case it saves it, though.

Comment: @Dane Ultimately, I’m not convinced, but I also don’t think it’s that big a deal. We used to accept questions like this, and it got some answers, but this kind of thing we don’t do anymore, so... I got an upvote and so figured it was time to close in case people saw this and got the wrong idea about asking their own questions.

Comment: For the sake of posterity: should future people also refrain from asking questions about fluff justification for D&D Druid class abilities/spells? Or is it only the alignment part of this question that makes it a bad example?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why would it be unnatural? The druid’s magic *is* part of the nature of their world. Channeling some of that power into a creature is no more unnatural than bringing water to a field to help it grow. Sure, the water wouldn’t have gone there “naturally,” if by that you mean without the druid taking an active role in making it go there, but the druid himself is a natural creature.

The important thing is that *awaken* empowers the creature to be a better representative of its kind. It enhances the creature without twisting it, the way, perhaps, a transmuter (e.g. owlbear) or necromancer (e.g. undead) or even an angel (e.g. celestial creature) might.

Also, evil druids are still just as in favor of the “natural” as are good or neutral druids, they just use the power of nature to empower themselves, to the detriment of those around them.

Answer (score 14):

While it's certainly a niche spell you won't come across that often, it does have some uses.

### Sentient Trees

Awaken works on plants as well as animals. If you have a favorite campsite, you could Awaken some trees around it to act as sentries and guards. This is not a particularly efficient use of XP, but would make some very neat flavor for a Druid's grove. It could also be used to scare off poachers of low level (like common townsfolk).

### Animal Spies

For animals, intelligent animals can be useful as spies. Nobody thinks twice about a cat going around town. A cat that can speak common would be a fairly useful scout in the home of someone you want to watch, especially if it's their cat. A few of them could cover a town and know what's going on.

### Friends

In both cases, as the targets are sentient, you can befriend them. They start off friendly, but you could work to make them cohorts or allies the same as any other friendly NPC. This can let you do some interesting things.

Theoretically if a DM allowed it, another PC could actually play one of these as a character. That would be... different.

### Attack

As Ellesedil mentioned in his comment, you could also use it to attack someone who is mistreating an animal companion by making that animal intelligent. It's now no longer their companion, and with it's intelligence it may harbor a grudge. (Note that this won't work on a familiar or Paladin mount, as both are treated as Magical Beasts.)

I suppose you could also ask your newly sentient animals to attack. Although the spell says they will serve you "in specific tasks or endeavors", they are sentient beings now and can't just be bossed around endlessly. So that is not very practical either.

You don't see PCs doing that very often because of the XP cost, but I can see a situation where NPCs could have a lot of fun with it.

### Is it Evil?

I don't think using this spell is inherently evil. If you're using it to release an animal companion in the service of an evil Druid, that is not an evil act. Making an intelligent tree around a Druidic grove doesn't seem like an evil act.

If you're using Awaken on an animal so that you can experiment or torture something intelligent, that would be evil. I'd argue, however, that it's the evil act itself and not the awaken that makes it so.

As with a lot of spells it's possible to use it in an evil way, but I don't see anything overtly evil about this one. You could definitely make a case that it's not *natural* and that any given Druid might react negatively to other Druids using it. That would be perfectly legitimate character opinion, but that's essentially politics and not something for the alignment system.

### Where did it come from?

I don't have a specific source that would justify that. [The AD&D PHB had a spell called Animate Rock](http://pandaria.rpgworlds.info/cant/rules/adnd_spells.htm#Animate%20Rock) ([alternate source](http://www.seads.org/TSR/phbbk.htm)). That works similarly to Awaken (actually like Animate Object), only on rocks, and was also available to Clerics. A likely explanation is that the 3.0 designers wanted to keep the spell but realized that doing it to rocks doesn't actually make a whole lot of sense for Druids, so when Druids got their own spell list they gave them a more Druidic themed version.

Magical Beasts (which include intelligent animals) are already in the game, however. There's also sentient plants like Treants, although the spell doesn't let you create those specifically. It seems like a better fit than animated rocks.

Comment: The AD&D 2e PHB (1995 reprint) did indeed have Animate Rock as a 7th level priest spell usable by clerics and druids. In D&D 3e the priest spell list was split into separate cleric and druid lists, which probably inspired _awaken_ as a kind of druid equivalent to _animate dead_ and _animate object_. It may be inspired by the Tolkien tree ents/treants, and intelligent animals from folklore and cartoons.

Comment: If you use Awaken in the hopes of gaining an ally (say, for combat), you could try to convert him/her/it into a cohort.

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that *awaken* doesn't actually give you much ability to control the target. For any target other than your most recent, the creature starts out friendly toward you and understands that you're responsible for its sentience, but after that moment, its attitude (and willingness to help) is no more under your control than anyone else's is. Your most recent target is essentially charmed, but that's not domination, and it only works on one target anyway. Either way, if you treat these creatures badly enough to lose their friendship -which is harder for your most recent target, owing to the charm-like effect, but still not impossible- they will leave.

Also, to add to the list of possible uses, imagine a pack of animals that is constantly being harassed by humanoids; it might even be subject to poaching. A druid might *awaken* the leader of such a pack, or several of its stronger members, so that they can better protect the pack.

For a truly fantastic example, consider the possibility that one of these stronger members eventually becomes a druid himself. This could result in a self-perpetuating society where all the mature packmates are *awakened*, and the druid *awakens* the young after reaching a certain age, eventually training a successor.

If you really want to get exotic, this might even form the basis for an interesting DMPC (or even a PC, if a player feels up to the challenge of playing a species without opposable thumbs). The pack has lost its only remaining druid, and has sent out one of its members to learn the ways of the class and, most importantly, the secret of *awakening*. If he fails, then the pack will revert to nonsentience as the *awakened* members die out.

Comment: "Initially friendly" is **way** less effect than *charm*. *Charm* forces the target to treat you like their best friend and puts considerable reinforcement on that notion despite (many of) your actions that might contradict it.

Comment: The pathfinder description goes beyond just "initially friendly," though, at least for the most recent target. It says that the most recent target will actually do what you want if you ask, and specifically contrasts that with earlier targets, which are still friendly but won't necessarily do what you want unless it actually makes some sense to do so. I agree that the effect on the most recent target is somewhat weaker than a charm, but the basic principle still seems to apply.

Answer (score -1):

This comes out in many ways, but there is obviously a use for the spell in many terms. I am in a conquest campaign, in which I have messages needing to be sent from time to time. I could either use spell slots to animal message or whatever for every occasion or I could have a flock of sentient giant eagles who do so for me which is my intent with the coming level. I am in need of man power and this spell is a reliable way to create trust worthy NPCs.

I can also assign hidden guards to myself/ allies, I am still attempting to find a way to staff my ships. Most beasts with thumbs are to smart for the spell to affect them.

Comment: This is pretty much a designer reasoning in disguise, so where do you base your reasoning on? Sources!

Comment: Welcome to the RPG Stack Exchange! My question is admittedly brief. What I was trying to get at is that the spell might be *useful*, but Druids abstain from many useful things (metal armor is a biggie) because of the fluff about being _natural_. Your answer also illustrates the PC-centric reasoning that bothered me: are the awakened animals going to be indentured servants/slaves? Why are they going to indefinitely serve the Druid?