# can a hierophant druid impersonate people?

Tags: druid, adnd-2e, disguise

The hierophant druid has this particular power:

> The ability to alter the appearance at will. (...) Body and facial features can resemble any human or humanoid creature.

That he could look like a gnoll, elf, orc, halfling or mongrelman, that is a given. But is this alteration good enough to pass as someone else?

Comment: [This might also be of interest.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/27873/8610)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Thanks for linking. I think the 2e version is more powerful (even if just because it is from a level where PC are already in epic-level territory).

Answer (score 2):

The RAW in your quoted text has the answer.

"You can alter your appearance at will" means that you can make your nose longer, your hair shorter, change the color of your eyes, etc.  So because you can also change your race, you can also change those features of the new race until you exactly match a specified target.

Also not the wording in the other sentence, "Body and facial features *can resemble any human* or humanoid creature."  If you separate the sentence into two separate ideas, removing the conjunction "or", then you get: *Body and facial features can resemble any human.  Body and facial features can resemble any humanoid creature.*  In both cases, the wording specifically allows transforming adapting your body and facial features to resemble an individual creature, ***any*** individual creature, as long as they are humanoid.  The fact that it says "human or humanoid creature" seems redundant, but by separating it out into two concepts like this, it makes the rules more clear, since turning into any *human* is pretty much the same as turning into any *person*.

Since this is at will, you could even add details as you found out about them, so when the real prince says, "I can prove I am the prince!  See!  Here is my secret birthmark in the shape of a penguin!"  You can reply with, "And here is mine!"

The real problem with impersonations would probably be things like speech patterns and manerisms.

Comment: You are right, I improved the wording.  I really meant to point out the fact that you would need to be able to do some acting too.

Comment: This would be covered by the Disguise proficiency. In the rogue group...

Comment: Right, my point was that it would not be part of the same ability.